# How can I allow downloading of files inside my android webview app?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I need to make my android webview app be able to download files when the download is initiated by code on the webpage.

I am not at all familiar with android app development, or Java for that matter, so please have patience. On my webpage that the webview app accesses, there is javascript code that initiates a download using a blob object, like so:

```
let blob = new Blob([filestring]);
let downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = downloadUrl;
link.download = currentpage + '.csv';
link.click();
URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
```

I have tried to allow the download to work inside of the webview application, but when I pressing the button that runs the above javascript code on the page, the webview application crashes. I cannot figure out why this doesn't work.

Here is the MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.example.stockapptestbeta;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.os.Environment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });
        mywebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (StockAppAndroid) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/107.0.5304.105 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.22");
        mywebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));

                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageFinished(view,url);
            CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StockAppTestBeta"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Does anybody know how to make this download functionality work? Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. First, create these three variables in your class.

```
private String sFileName, sUrl, sUserAgent;
```

Then in your onCreate in your activity, create a download listener for your webview.

```
    myWebview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,getFileType(url));
            sFileName = filename;
            sUrl = url;
            sUserAgent = userAgent;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    downloadFile(filename,url,userAgent);
                }else {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1001);
                }
            }else {
                downloadFile(filename,url,userAgent);
            }

        }
    });
```

Add a webchrome client in OnCreate.

```
   myWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
            super.onPermissionRequest(request);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        }

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```

Permission is needed for writing files on your device. Add this to your OnRequestPermissionsResult code.

```
  @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode==1001){
            if (grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if (!sUrl.equals("")&&!sFileName.equals("")&&!sUserAgent.equals("")){
                    downloadFile(sFileName,sUrl,sUserAgent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then create a function called downloadFile.

```
private void downloadFile(String filename, String url, String userAgent) {
    try {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(url));

        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Downloading File...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        sUrl = "";
        sFileName = "";
        sUserAgent = "";
    }catch (Exception ignored){
        Toast.makeText(this, ignored.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This should work assuming the javascript code in your webpage is also working.